# Connecting to BT Infinity with cisco PPPoE

Tags: internet, pppoe

So I've been trying to get my cisco router to connect to the internet.

I've got the PPPoE working, I think, becuase I enabled debugging and saw that it authenticated correctly, and it also gives my dialer interface an IP address.

But, I can't ping the internet (8.8.8.8) or the dialer interface ...

Here's my config:

```
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname RouterName
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no logging console
enable secret 5 password
!
no aaa new-model
ip cef
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 2
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
username name privilege 5 password 7 password
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group gloabl
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Dialer1
 ip address negotiated
 ip access-group 101 in
 no ip unreachables
 ip mtu 1492
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 ppp chap hostname username@bt.com
 ppp chap password 7 password
 ppp pap sent-username username@bt.com password 7 password
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 101 interface Dialer1 overload
!
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

And here's my dialer interface getting it's ip:

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
FastEthernet0/1            192.168.0.254   YES NVRAM  up                    up
NVI0                       unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
Virtual-Access1            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Dialer1                    XXX.XXX.XX.XX   YES IPCP   up                    up
```

And lastly, here's my routes:

```
XX.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 2 subnets
C       XXX.XXX.XX.XX is directly connected, Dialer1
C       XXX.XXX.YY.1 is directly connected, Dialer1
     192.168.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       192.168.0.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
S*   0.0.0.0/0 is directly connected, Dialer1
```

I've ran out of ideas here ... Has anyone got any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, BT Infinity uses VDSL to dial the connection, then PPPoE on top.

The BT HomeHub v5 has a VDSL modem built-in, and will plug directly into your wall socket. Older versions will require a white BT OpenReach modem, which will dial the VDSL connection and allow you to use a third-party router for the PPPoE part.

As you have the OpenReach modem, I would check your firewall/NAT setup to ensure that the relevant rules have been created to allow traffic between LAN and WAN.

Comment: I'm using the OpenReach modem

Comment: Answer edited :)

Comment: Haha, thanks :D ... But the modem has no firewall/NAT,it's all configured through the Cisco router, which only has NAT at the moment